# How to refer back to an array of points, to score each character that user has been asked to input, C

Tags: arrays, c, function, for-loop

So, I have an array that looks like this:

```
// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet

 int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};
```

In order, each integer in the array is correspondent to a letter from the alphabet. A or a, is worth 1 point, B or b is worth 3 points.

And I have prompted user for an input, how would I go about evaluating the user input and comparing it to the positions of the integers inside of an array and later?

I know I must create a function and inside of that function use some sort of a loop, but I'm not sure what should the check condition inside the loop be.
I also guess that I should convert my inputted string, to an integer, hopefully getting back ASCII number.

```
// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{
    // Get input words from both players
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    // Score both words
    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
    int score2 = compute_score(word2);

    // TODO: Print the winner
}

int compute_score(string word)
{
    // TODO: Compute and return score for string
}
```

I am not quite sure how to and what to compute exactly inside of my compute_score function.

Comment: Too broad...can you be a little more specific?

Comment: I've updated my post with my code, it might make more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help you with the logic (based on my understanding of the question).

Assuming you're on a platform with [ASCII character encoding](http://www.asciitable.com/) (which has strictly increasing serial values for alphabets):

- Read user input using `fgets()`.
- After stripping newline from the input, measure the length of the input.
- Loop over each element in the input, and

  - if the value of the input is between `'A'` and `'Z'`, subtract `'A'` from the value, and use that as the index  value to find the weight from the `POINTS` array.
  - else if the value of the input is between `'a'` and `'z'`, subtract `'a'` from the value, and use that as the index  value to find the weight from the `POINTS` array.
  - else, skip to next value.
- Keep on adding the values till the last element in the user input and decide outcome based on the final value.

Answer (score 0):

i think this could work :

```
int get_letter_nb(char c)
    {
        if (c > 64 && c < 91)
            return (c - 64);
        if (c > 96 && c < 123)
            return (c - 96);
        return (-1)      // error : it's not a letter
    }

int compute_score(string word)
{
    int count = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; word[i], i++) {
        if (temp = get_letter_nb(word[i]) == -1)
            return (-1);          // error : handling
        count += temp;
    }
    return POINTS[count];
}
```

ask for any question, i'm taking the ascii code of the letter in the `get_letter_nb` and i substract for have A or a == 1

exemple 'a' == 97 in ascii so i return 97 - 97 then 'a' equals 0 and in your array it's POINTS[0] for a

feel free to ask ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this result by creating another array of actual letters, LETTERS. Because the number values in your POINTS array are arranged in the correct order corresponding to their alphabetical letters, that means that the index of 'a' in the array of actual letters, LETTERS would correspond to its value in the POINTS array.

To complete the implementation of the program in compute_score(), we can loop through both the LETTERS array and the 'word' string given as the argument and check if the character at word[index] is equal to the character at LETTERS[index] then because the LETTERS array has characters whose index corresponds to their score values at the same index in the POINTS array, we can get the index of the character in LETTERS and get its value at POINTS[letter_index_in_LETTERS] then add that value from POINTS to a counter, score.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};
char LETTERS[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
                  'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};

int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{
    // Get input words from both players
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    // Score both words
    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
    int score2 = compute_score(word2);

    // TODO: Print the winner
    if (score1 > score2)
    {
        printf("player 1 wins! \n");
    }
    else if (score1 < score2)
    {
        printf("player 2 wins! \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("tie! \n");
    }
}

int compute_score(string word)
{
    // TODO: Compute and return score for string
    int stringLength = strlen(word);

    // keep track of the score
    int score = 0;

    // looping through the word so we can have individual letters compared with their position in Letters array
    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
    {

        // convert all upperCase letters to lowerCase letters equivalent to the ones in LETTERS
        char letterInWord = tolower(word[i]);

        
        for (int j = 0, arraySize = sizeof(LETTERS) / sizeof(LETTERS[1]); j < arraySize; j++)
        {
            // if the character at index i is not a letter then we have to add 0 to score
            if (isalpha(word[i]) == 0)
            {
                score += 0;
            }
            else if (LETTERS[j] == letterInWord)
            {
                // if the characters match then we get the index of the character in LETTERS to find out its relative score
                // This is possible because we have created our LETTERS array in the same order we have been told the POINTS are
                // made
                printf("currently adding %i to score because of %c", POINTS[j], word[i]);
                score += POINTS[j];
            }
        }
    }

    return score;
}
```

However, be cautious with how you prompt the user for word1 and word2. This is so because the get_string() method is not a built in function  in C but is provided by the <cs50.h> header tag which is used in the cs50 courses by Harvard university so the actual code provided may not work if this header is not used in your code. I have only used it in my solution because the author of the problem included it in their code snippet in the question.
TAKE NOTE OF THAT!